# ERROR: Error processing {'productname': [], 'productphoto': [], 'productprice': []} in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to python scrapy and I trying to fetch data from an online grocery shop. It has a crawled status of 200 but it did not scrape anything. It shows in the console log that IndexError: list index out of range and ERROR: Error processing {'productname': [], 'productphoto': [], 'productprice': []}

Spider file:

```
class productspider(scrapy.Spider):
        name        =   'products'
        start_urls   =   [
            'https://www.meenaclick.com/category/fish'
    
        ]
    
    
        def parse(self, response):
            # open_in_browser(response)
            # all_div_quotes   =   response.css('div.quote')
    
            items    =   BestdealscraperItem()
    
            product_name = response.css('.p-sm .m0').css('::text').extract()
            product_price = response.css('.reg-price::text').extract()
            product_photo = response.css('.ng-lazyloaded::attr(src)').extract()
            # product_link = response.css('.mtb-title').extract()
    
    
            items['productname'] = product_name
            items['productprice'] = product_price
            items['productphoto'] = product_photo
    
            yield items
```

Pipeline file:
class BestdealscraperPipeline(object):

```
        def __init__(self):
            self.create_connection()
            self.create_table()
    
        def create_connection(self):
            self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host    =   'localhost',
                user    = 'root',
                passwd  = 'imnumber47',
                database    = 'crawledata',
            )
            self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
    
        def create_table(self):
            self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bestdealproductdb""")
            self.curr.execute("""
                    create table bestdealproductdb(
                        productname text,
                        productprice int,
                        productphoto text
                    )""")
    
    
    
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
    
            self.store_db(item)
    
            # print('pipeline:' + item['productname'][0])
            return item
    
        def store_db(self, item):
                self.curr.execute("""insert into bestdealproductdb values(%s,%s,%s) """,(
    
                    item['productname'][0],
                    item['productprice'][0],
                    item['productphoto'][0]
                )
                
                
                )
    
                self.conn.commit()
```

Console log:

```
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 58 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 59 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 60 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 61 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 70 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 81 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 82 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2022-02-18 23:47:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.meenaclick.com/category/fish> (referer: None)
2022-02-18 23:47:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'productname': [], 'productphoto': [], 'productprice': []}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\bestdealscraping\bestenv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "d:\bestdealscraping\bestenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "D:\BestDealScraping\bestdealscraper\bestdealscraper\pipelines.py", line 39, in process_item
    self.store_db(item)
  File "D:\BestDealScraping\bestdealscraper\bestdealscraper\pipelines.py", line 47, in store_db
    item['productname'][0],
IndexError: list index out of range
2022-02-18 23:47:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-02-18 23:47:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 525,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4592,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.827048,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 18, 17, 47, 52, 6976)
```

,

Comment: You should use scrapy+selenium, content loaded dynamically via javascript.

Comment: Sir I have used Scrapy + Selenium as you suggested. But it came up with the same type of problem. You can see the details in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257872/productname-none-productphoto-none-productprice-none-css-selector)

Answer (score 0):

The Python problem is rather straightforward: `item['productname'][0]` fails because `item['productname']` is empty, which means that

```
response.css('.p-sm .m0').css('::text').extract()
```

did not find any matches.

As Samsul Islam pointed out, the underlying problem is that the website dynamically loads its content. This means that it's not enough to just parse the initial HTML document, you also need to execute the Javascript code which then alters the DOM in place. You can learn more about how to use Scrapy with dynamically loaded content here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

In this specific example, the data is retrieved from https://api.meenaclick.com/api/front/products/category/fish using a POST request. You can reverse engineer the type of request you need to make to get the data (see the Scrapy docs for more in depth information) and once you have done it, there is no need to scrape anything or write HTML selectors. You can just directly work with the parsed JSON data.